# How to get selected Allowed country list in Magento 2..?

Tags: magento-2.1, phtml, countries

I need to get the the Selected Allowed Countries in a phtml file..

How can i get that ?

Comment: you have created custom or for default ?

Answer (score 6):

You can fetch the Allowed Countries List using the below Code:

```
public function __construct(
    /* Add below dependencies */
    \Magento\Directory\Model\AllowedCountries $allowedCountryModel
) {
    $this->allowedCountryModel = $allowedCountryModel;
}

//Call the below function to fetch countires        
$this->allowedCountryModel->getAllowedCountries()
```

Comment: this returns only shortcode of all countries. How can i get full names too?

Comment: This only returns the countries for the default store. Is there a way to return the countries from all stores?

Answer (score 2):

You can utilise the `getCountryCollection` method in Magento's Directory Helper as it filters the returned collection to contain allowed countries only.

Example:

```
use Magento\Directory\Helper\Data as DirectoryHelper;
use Magento\Directory\Model\Country;

/**
 * Allowed Countries
 */
class AllowedCountriesProvider {

   /**
    * @var DirectoryHelper
    */
    protected $directoryHelper;

   /**
    * @param DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper
    */
    public function __construct(
        DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper
    )
    {
        $this->directoryHelper = $directoryHelper;
    }

   /**
    * Allowed Countries Getter.
    */
    public function getAllowedCountries()
    {
        $countries = [];

        /* @var Country $country */
        foreach ($this->directoryHelper->getCountryCollection() as $country) {
            $countries[] = [
                'value' => $country->getId(),
                'label' => $country->getName()
            ];
        }

        return $countries;
    }
}
```

Reference:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Directory/Helper/Data.php#L174

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Directory/Model/ResourceModel/Country/Collection.php#L160