# I have multistore website, stores are like A, B, C, D and its respective country is W, X, Y, Z. country selection based on website entered in magento2

Tags: magento2.3, customer-account, shipping-address, customer-address, checkout-page

I have a multistore website in magento2 my stores are like A, B, C, D and its respective country is W, X, Y, Z and I have limited shipping like I want shipping only for four countries. suppose customer want order from website A then  the country should be W, and the customer wants order from website B then the country should be X etc.

So I want country should be display based on entered website. On checkout page shipping address and billing address in magento2.

Comment: I don't get what you want. You can already update the customer adresses from your back office. And why removing the address access from the customer himself ?

Comment: @Claims, can you please check my above updated question.

Answer (score 0):

From your updated question : It seems that all you want to do is to "print" the selectected available country based on your backend configuration.

All backend configurations are saved in the database in the table `core_config_data` so all you have to do it get it from there using scope config.

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue(YOUR_VARIABLE_PATH, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

I haven't check more than that but I suspect that the good path is `general/country/allow`

This is where you defined your allowed countries from your backend.

> On the Admin sidebar, go to Stores > Settings > Configuration.
> In the left panel under General, choose General.
> Expand Expansion selector the Country Options section.
> Choose the Default Country where your business is located.
> In the Allow Countries list, select each country from which you accept orders.

To get the list; you can call this from your block into your template

```
public function __construct(
    /* Add below dependencies */
    \Magento\Directory\Model\AllowedCountries $allowedCountryModel
) {
    $this->allowedCountryModel = $allowedCountryModel;
}

//Call the below function to fetch countires        
$this->allowedCountryModel->getAllowedCountries()
```

Cf : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/200368/89569

Comment: How to set the country value  for front customer my account address section in Magento2

Comment: @Webdeveloper Check updated answer